# Is it true that going up multiple steps is harmful?

Tags: health, health-risk, walking, heart-rate, stairs

Once in a week I make a 2.5 hours walk that in the middle of it there is a few hundred steps up.

A friend of mine (that has nothing to do with fitness) just told me recently that upclimbing steps is harmful for your heart. Is that true?

P.S. I have no history of health issues.

Comment: could you tell us more about yourself?  How old are you?  Do you have a history of high blood pressure?  Has a doctor told you to avoid stairs?  Do your knees hurt when you climb them?  Fit individuals would probably have no problem handling going up a few hundred steps, someone with a history of medical problems may, its not possible to give a single answer that covers everybody.

Comment: @DavidR question updated.

Comment: you haven't completely updated your question by those questions asked by @DavidR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look and was not able to find any evidence of harm from stair climbing. On the contrary, stair climbing is positively correlated with good heart health in [previously sedentary women](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0091743500906340) and [post-college males](http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/707484).

Unless you are at risk of heart issues, moderate stair climbing is no more dangerous than other activities.

Comment: second link is broken

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Climbing steps will raise the heart rate more than walking. Generally, that is a good thing; you get more of a workout, burn more calories, and improve your aerobic fitness.

If you are generally good help, the more stairs the better.